# Android: Amazon ads never retrieved, AdListener never called

Tags: android, amazon-advertising-api

I am trying to implement Amazon Ads in my Android app, but have not been able to get any ads to display. The message in my logs is always:

```
D/AmazonMobileAds DefaultAdListener: Default ad listener called - Ad Failed to Load. Error code: NO_FILL, Error Message: Server Message: no results
```

I have set up my account, verified my tax information, I have an application key. I have tried both with testing enable and disabled with the same results. I have followed the guide for loading ads from both Amazon and Admob for backfill, but the AdMob ads are then not retrieved either. If I retrieve just AdMob ads, I have no problem with them. The relevant code is below:

in onCreate():

```
    AdRegistration.setAppKey(getString(R.string.amazon_ad_id));
    AdRegistration.enableTesting(true);
    AdRegistration.enableLogging(true);

    // Initialize ad views
    amazonAdView = new com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout(this);
    amazonAdView.setListener(new MyAdListener());

    admobAdView = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView(this);
    admobAdView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    admobAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
```

Method called to retrieve an ad:

```
void getAd(){
    // Initialize view container
    adViewContainer = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    amazonAdEnabled = true;
    adViewContainer.removeAllViews();
    adViewContainer.addView(amazonAdView);

    AdTargetingOptions adOptions = new AdTargetingOptions();
    adOptions.enableGeoLocation(true);
    amazonAdView.loadAd(adOptions);
}
```

Inner AdListener class

```
class MyAdListener extends DefaultAdListener {

    public void onAdLoaded(com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout view, AdProperties adProperties) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ad Loaded");
        if (!amazonAdEnabled) {
            amazonAdEnabled = true;
            adViewContainer.removeView(admobAdView);
            adViewContainer.addView(amazonAdView);
        }
    }

    public void onAdFailedToLoad(com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout view, AdError error) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ad Failed to load");
        // Call AdMob SDK for backfill
        if (amazonAdEnabled) {
            amazonAdEnabled = false;
            adViewContainer.removeView(amazonAdView);
            adViewContainer.addView(admobAdView);
        }
        admobAdView.loadAd((new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder()).build());
    }
}
```

In my logging, neither of the statements from the AdListener shows, so it appears that the listener is never being called. So, I have two issues here:

1. Why am I always receiving a NO_FILL response, even when testing?
2. Why is the listener never called?